# setInterval() inside plugin function not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a jQuery slideshow plugin that I am making though it has a `setInterval()` inside it which is not being called though if I move the contents of the `setInterval()` outside of the it then it works though it only runs once.

```
var gap = 3;
var duration = 0.5;
(function ($) {
    $.fn.slideshow = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            g = gap * 1000;
            d = duration * 1000;
            $(this).children().css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'display': 'none'
            });
            $(this).children().eq(0).css({
                'display': 'block'
            });
            setInterval(function () {
                slide();
            }, g);

            function slide() {
                $(this)
                    .children()
                    .eq(0)
                    .fadeOut(d)
                    .next()
                    .fadeIn()
                    .end()
                    .appendTo($(this).children().eq(0).parent());
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
$('.slideshow').slideshow();
```

HTML:

```
<div class='slideshow'>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>2</a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a>4</a>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle with my plugin:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/GrtLC/

Comment: relevant code needs to also be included in the question.

Comment: You're mis-diagnosing the problem. the setInterval is being called and the code within it is being called. http://jsfiddle.net/GrtLC/2/ What's different is what `this` is referencing.

Comment: Then why is the code not looping

Comment: console.log(this) in both places. They're differen't arent they?

Comment: If I have the code not in a setinterval it works though it only plays once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `this` inside the `slider` function does not point to the object you think it points to.

```
        setInterval($.proxy(function () {
            slide.call(this);
        }, this), g);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mRHPb/)

or better

```
setInterval($.proxy(slide, this), g);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mRHPb/3/)

Comment: Short and simple, but I think OP deserves a bit more explanation of how the magic works. :-)

Comment: Am I the only one that thought of "The Princess Bride" after reading this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `this` is always locally defined; by the time you get into the `setInterval()`, you've lost your original `this` (it's reset to the `window` object).

There are a few ways to get around this; the simplest is probably to copy `this` into a local variable.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/GrtLC/5/

```
var gap = 3;
var duration = 0.5;
(function ($) {
    $.fn.slideshow = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            g = gap * 1000;
            d = duration * 1000;
            $this = $(this); // caches the jQuery object as a further optimization
            $this.children().css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'display': 'none'
            });
            $this.children().eq(0).css({
                'display': 'block'
            });
            setInterval(function () {
                slide($this); // pass $this into the function
            }, g);

            function slide($obj) {
                $obj.children()
                    .eq(0)
                    .fadeOut(d)
                    .next()
                    .fadeIn()
                    .end()
                    .appendTo($obj.children().eq(0).parent());
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
$('.slideshow').slideshow();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot work, because your callback is not bound to the this; try instead

```
var that = this;

setInterval(function () {
    slide();
}, g);

function slide() {
    $(that) ....
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside `slide` function is not the slideshow. I make it work caching the object inside the `each` loop: http://jsfiddle.net/x7Jk8/